# jQuery Slider: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined

Tags: jquery, exception, slider

I have the following jquery slider code:

```
    $(function() {
    var select = $( "#ppp" );
    var slider = $( "<div id='slider' style='width:575px;'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
        min: 3,
        max: 60,
        range: "min",
        value: window.slidervalue,
        step:3,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            select[ 0 ].value = ui.value;

        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            document.getElementById('vpp').innerHTML=ui.value;
            show_products('1','Y','N','N','N','N','Y');
        }
    });
```

window.slidervalue refers to a number set somewhere else. #ppp refers to 
 When I was using jQuery 1.7.2 everything was going fine. When I however switched over to 1.8.1 it threw an exception:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined" No idea why...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.8.1 is now also in testing and development phase and there are some bugs - use 1.7.2 instead if you have no errors with that

Comment: The problem exists in 1.8.0 as well. I only encountered it when I started using Google's JQuery hosting feature:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js Why don't they (Google) only use stable versions for their hosting facility? I switched it now back again to 1.7.2 hosted on my own server

Comment: well 1.8 versions are still under testing so they are not fully reliable

Comment: better wait for a more reliable version of 1.8 and they switch to that till that 1.7.2 is the best available version

Comment: If it's still in beta it's stupid then that they classify it as stable :S

Comment: This problem still exists in 1.8.2 also

Answer (score 2):

1.8.1 seems to be buggy in some points - i would prefer using 1.7.2 if you have no errors are do you need 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists in 1.8.2 as well, and after Michael's comment, I guess 1.8.0, 1.8.1 and 1.8.2 are all having this same issue.
Personally I was using 1.8.2 and now I had to switch to 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined"

I had this issue with 1.8.20, but it does not occur for me with 1.10.0